# state.go not change page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**UPDATE**:

when the instruction of state.go is execute the url chenge from

`http/localhost:8100/login.html`

into

`http/localhost:8100/login.html#/main.html`

i'm developing an app and using `$state.go();` it doesn't chenge the page, i've did a quick debug with the console and i haven't received any errors.
I've also tried `$location.path();` and the result is the same.
in the moment i'm trying to change page after the login, so from login.html to main.html that are in the same folder
This is my code:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ui.router'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})


.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    //abstract : true, // Because your are have child-states under de 'splash' state, you should set it abstract : true;
    templateUrl: '/login.html',
    controller: "LogiCtrl"
  })

    .state('main', {
        url: "/main",
        templateUrl: "templates/main.html",
    })
}])


.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state, $ionicHistory) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.funzione = "login";
    $scope.submit = function(){
        console.clear();
        console.log("Dentro funzione");
        console.log($scope.data.funzione);
        var link = 'http://localhost/<path>/api.php';
        $http.post(link, {mail : $scope.data.mail}, {pwd : $scope.data.pwd}, {funzione : $scope.data.funzione})
            .then(function (res){
                console.log("Dentro http.post");
                $scope.response = res.data;
                console.log($scope.response);
                if ($scope.response != "F"){
                    console.log("Dentro if");
                    $state.go('main');
                } else {
                    console.log("Dentro else");
                }
            });
    };
});
```

**EDIT**

[image]

How can i solved this problem?

Thank's

Comment: `templateUrl: "templates/main.html"` should be `templateUrl: "/main.html"` because your main.html file is in root. Other things looking okay.

Answer (score 0):

In your config, change `LogiCtrl` to `LoginCtrl`

**EDIT** In your config again, change `login.html` to `templates/login.html`, since you said they're in the same folder.

Comment: Why are you giving us a bad code if you want help ? Correct it yourself first.

Comment: Well, everything I'd say. You have a wrong controller name but your application works ? Your files are "in the same folder", but in your config none of them are in the actual folder, and you get no error ? Give us a working code and we can help you.

Comment: sorry, the templateUrl in this question is wrong but because was a test, with templateUrl: main.html i've not errors but the page not change

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your login.html is not in `templates` folder. 
I think it should look like this:  `templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',`.

Comment: is in www not in templates

Comment: I just want to be sure if you debugged your code, does it successfully login ?? did you put a breakpoint inside the login callback function ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128840/discussion-between-nadeem-khoury-and-edoardo).